# Is there a way to make JPA ignore invalid types of enum?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

There's a Microservice I'm working on, that used to have one kind of Enum related to one of it's columns, but now I had to change it.

```
@Convert(converter = TypeEnumConverter.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "TIPO", length = 40, nullable = false)
private TypeEnum type;
```

It's mapped like that, but the enums names and types are imcompatible, is there a way to tell JPA to ignore it if it can't transform back to that enum?

Comment: what do you mean by "ignore it"? set the `type` field to `null`?

Comment: Yes. It's trying to convert an invalid type (from the database, older enum type) and it causes an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 10):

You can implement a [custom enum mapping using an AttributeConverter](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/). Within the converter, you could then map unknown enum values to `null`. But please be aware that the next update operation would then remove the value from that database column.

You already reference your `TypeEnumConverter` attribute converter in the `@Convert` annotation in your mapping. If you want to use it, you need to remove the `@Enumerated` annotation. The JPA specification doesn't allow you to use these 2 annotations together because both define how the Enum values get mapped.

## Implementation Example

Here is an example of how such a mapping could look like.

### My Enum

I use this simple `Vehicle` enum:

```
public enum Vehicle {
 
    BUS, CAR, TRAIN, PLANE;
}
```

### My Attribute Converter

The [attribute converter](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) implements the mapping between the Java object and the value stored in your database. It's a simple Java class that implements the `AttributeConverter` interface and is annotated with `@Converter`. If you set the `autoApply` attribute to true, it will be automatically used for all entity attributes of the converted type.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class VehicleConverter implements AttributeConverter<Vehicle, String> {
 
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Vehicle vehicle) {
        switch (vehicle) {
        case Vehicle.BUS:
            return "B";
 
        case Vehicle.CAR:
            return "C";
 
        case Vehicle.TRAIN:
            return "T";
 
        case Vehicle.PLANE:
            return "P";
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public Vehicle convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        switch (dbData) {
        case "B":
            return Vehicle.BUS;
 
        case "C":
            return Vehicle.CAR;
 
        case "T":
            return Vehicle.TRAIN;
 
        case "P":
            return Vehicle.PLANE;
 
        default:
            // ignore unknown values
            return null;
        }
    }
 
}
```

### My Entity Class

You can then use the enum without any additional mapping annotations in your entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Trip {
     
    private Vehicle vehicle;
 
    ...
}
```

Comment: You said: 
But please be aware that the next update operation would then remove the value from that database column.
What exactly did you mean by that?

Comment: If your AttributeConverter sets the attribute value to null and your business code changes any of the other entity attributes, Hibernate will generate an SQL UPDATE statement and set the value of the converted enum to null.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind losing the legacy values in the DB that are incompatible with the current Enum then @Thorben response is the way to go.

If you want to preserve them, then one solution would be to declare your field as a String, and provide accessory methods to manipulate the value as an enum. Something like:

```
@Column(name = "TIPO", length = 40, nullable = false)
private String type;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public TypeEnum getTypeEnum() {
    try {
        return TypeEnum.valueOf(type);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
  
public void setTypeEnum(TypeEnum typeEnum) {
    if (typeEnum != null) {
        type = typeEnum.toString();
    }
}
```